# .Net 4.5.1 GridSplitter only decreases columns

Tags: wpf

I can't even fathom this. I have a gridsplitter in .net 4.5.1. I have created a new wpf application and then dropped the code below on the main window. **What I expect from this**: in a grid with two columns when I drag the splitter to the right the column in the right should decrease in size and the column on the left should increase. When I drag the splitter to the left the column to the left should descrease in size and the column on the right should in size. **The behavior I am seeing**: when I drag the splitter to the right the column on the right decreases in size and the column on the left decreases in size. So the two text boxes get smaller in width. When I drag the splitter to left the splitter stops at the center of the grid and nothing else happens.I have no minwidth or width. Does anyone have a clue on this one?

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hi" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Background="Transparent" ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

     <TextBox Grid.Column="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="there" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: what's the exact behavior you want here? a `GridSplitter` can just resize (shrink and grow) ***2 columns*** at the same time. In your code it resizes the current column and the third column (the next column). However the first column has `Width` the same as the third column's (both being equal to `*`). When you drag the grid to the left until the current column's width becomes `0`, it of course stops there and the left and right columns are equally `50%` of the whole grid's width.

Comment: I edited the question to better explain what is happening.

Comment: I've added the answer to this question. It's fairly easy to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well now I understand what you want. You are following an approach in which you reserve even a  column (the middle column) for the `GridSplitter`. To follow this approach, you need to specify the `ResizeBehavior` as `PreviousAndNext` to set the resizing behavior to resize the previous and the next columns letting the current (the middle) column untouched:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Background="Transparent" 
              ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
```

Also you don't need to specify a separate column for the `GridSplitter` when its `Width` is small enough and does not much bother the containing column's `Width`. That means you just need 2 columns, putting the `GridSplitter` in either the first or the second column does not really matter. But note that, when putting it in the second column, the `HorizontalAlignment` should be `Left`. And when putting it in the first column, the `HorizontalAlignment` should be `Right` (which is the default). The following code puts the `GridSplitter` in the second column. We place it after all the TextBoxes to be sure that it's rendered on top of the TextBoxes, otherwise you have to set the `Panel.ZIndex` explicitly and appropriately.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<TextBox Grid.Column="0" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hi" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="there"/>
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Background="Transparent" 
              ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```